# How to print SealedObject encrypted data without file I/O?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, password-encryption

Below is my code.
when I try to print sealed object it only displays

> "javax.crypto.SealedObject@34dac684"

```
private void encryptUserCodes(List<UserCode> userCodes) {

        try {
            // generate a secret key using the DES algorithm
            key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            // initialize the ciphers with the given key
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            // create a sealed object
            SealedObject sealed = new SealedObject((Serializable) userCodes, ecipher);
            //PRINT SEALED OBJECT HERE
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you print your object?

Comment: @Janez Kuhar System.out.println(sealed);

Comment: What do you expect in the print out ?

Comment: @Benoit i want it in the string for e.g. ("sdfdsgwet4tgsdgsfsgdfhgfhhfg==")

Comment: @Benoit i have tried using toString but still it prints the same, i want to print encrypted data

Comment: @Samir In short, you want to print the encrypted String ?

Comment: @user3437460, yes exactly

Comment: @All, Is there any other way to encrypt List of objects and print encrypted string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Encrypt:**

Create Outputstreams and use Base64 Encoder to get the String.

**2. Decrypt:**

Create a new Cipher, Inputstreams and use Base 64 Decoder to get back your original String.

Fully working example (just copy and paste):

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SealedObject;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.util.Base64;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass();
        myObject.print();
    }
}

// you can add other public classes to this editor in any order
class OtherClass
{
public void print() {


 try {
       String userCodes = "Test123";
        // generate a secret key using the DES algorithm
        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        // initialize the ciphers with the given key
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // create a sealed object
        SealedObject sealed = new SealedObject((Serializable) userCodes, ecipher);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
            outputStream, ecipher);

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);
    oos.writeObject( sealed );
    cipherOutputStream.close();

    byte[] values = outputStream.toByteArray();

    String base64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(values);
    System.out.println(base64encoded);

    // decrypt
    Cipher fcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    fcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    ByteArrayInputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encoded));
    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(istream, fcipher);
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
    SealedObject sealdedObject = (SealedObject) inputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println(sealdedObject.getObject(key));

}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution...but when I write only decryption code in other method  I got this error "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5C820B75"

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` will always print value of `toString()` method. In your case printing Class@hex is default implementation in Object class which gets inherited in all classes in java.

You can create a custom method to print the your object.

Provide method definition with traversing the desire result by calling getter methods  from your object and print them. Concatenation and return is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sealed` object is serializable. Thus you can write it to ObjectOutputStream:

```
try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
    out.writeObject(sealed);
    byte [] bytes =  bos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To print it more user friendly, you can encode it in base64:

```
String base64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
System.out.println(base64encoded);
```

Comment: Thank you @Benoit
got the response in a string
and what if I want to decrypt it from string

Comment: @Samir Then you have to use similarly `ByeArrayInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: The ObjectOutputStream would return a serialized representation of the class *instance* and not of the class *contents*.  That's not quite the same.  If the point was to say, be able to take the bytes of the encrypted string and decrypt them, this would not be satisfactory.  Though admittedly the question was not clear, so this could be exactly what he was looking for as well.